# Jsoup - How to get around some JavaScript which makes an AJAX request and uses Cookies?

Tags: android, jsoup

I've been using Jsoup to parse this [site](http://curaj.tv), and it was working great until the introduced a "loader", so now I get this answer:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>.loader-walk{width: 100px; height: 40px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}.loader-walk > div{content: ""; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #2196F3; border-radius: 100%; position: absolute; -webkit-animation: animate 2s linear infinite; animation: animate 2s linear infinite;}.loader-walk > div:nth-of-type(1){-webkit-animation-delay: -.4s; animation-delay: -.4s;}.loader-walk > div:nth-of-type(2){-webkit-animation-delay: -.8s; animation-delay: -.8s;}.loader-walk > div:nth-of-type(3){-webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s; animation-delay: -1.2s;}.loader-walk > div:nth-of-type(4){-webkit-animation-delay: -1.6s; animation-delay: -1.6s;}@-webkit-keyframes animate{0%{left: 100px; top: 0;}80%{left: 0; top: 0;}85%{left: 0; top: -20px; width: 20px; height: 20px;}90%{width: 40px; height: 15px;}95%{left: 100px; top: -20px; width: 20px; height: 20px;}100%{left: 100px; top: 0;}}@keyframes animate{0%{left: 100px; top: 0;}80%{left: 0; top: 0;}85%{left: 0; top: -20px; width: 20px; height: 20px;}90%{width: 40px; height: 15px;}95%{left: 100px; top: -20px; width: 20px; height: 20px;}100%{left: 100px; top: 0;}}</style>
      <title>Loading</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.min.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("a0623cecb54e0306f536ee8964960ca0"),b=toNumbers("d4e9cfdbae6dc103d3b28027ee549f5a"),c=toNumbers("dababf3e77151157fd19e2165cb9e367");document.cookie="BPC="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";document.location.href="http://curaj.tv/";</script>
      <div class="loader-walk">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I've playing with this for a few weeks and cannot get past this wall.

I could load the page in a background webView and parse it from there, but is not the way.

So how do I get past this "animation" screen?

P.S. I'm new to Jsoup, so please no hate.

Comment: What is wrong with loading it in background with webview?

Comment: It's loading very slow

Comment: Load the page in your desktop browser, open up the network tab of the developer tools, and see what It's loading and from where- it's very likely loading some JSON or something. Then it's just a matter of hitting the same URL with your code, get the data it returns, and figure out how to process it. ,You can also check out their script, maybe you can reverse enfpgineer it and figure out how it works. @Zack, WebView is very slow for these kind of things, and does not work well when used in the background.

Comment: You'll probably also have to extract some of the data from the page - in the second script tag there's some data which you'll probably have to send to the server with your request to get what you want. Extract this with a regex or something. Essentially, you'll have to emulate what the JavaScript does in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting hints given by JonasCz:

> Load the page in your desktop browser, open up the network tab of the developer tools, and see what It's loading and from where- it's very likely loading some JSON or something. Then it's just a matter of hitting the same URL with your code, get the data it returns, and figure out how to process it. ,You can also check out their script, maybe you can reverse enfpgineer it and figure out how it works. @Zack, WebView is very slow for these kind of things, and does not work well when used in the background.
>
> You'll probably also have to extract some of the data from the page - in the second script tag there's some data which you'll probably have to send to the server with your request to get what you want. Extract this with a regex or something. Essentially, you'll have to emulate what the JavaScript does in your code.